# Iterate over files in a folder (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to loop over files in a folder. I will not know what the names of the files will be when running the script, I just want to get the names.

I want it to run like this, but I can't figure out how. I understand why this does not work, but I do not understand how to make it work the way I want.

```
for (file in "./levels/") {
    console.log(file)
}
```

is there a way to make it run like this?

Comment: There is no way to make it run like that, no. You have to use the `fs` module Node provides. Read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured this out. using the fs module in node.js I am able to iterate over the files. here is the code I am using:

```
fs.readdirSync("./levels/").forEach((file) => {
     console.log(file)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const fs = require("fs");
fs.readdirSync(".levels/").forEach(file => {
    //Print file name
    console.log(file)

    /*
    Run this to print the file contents
    console.log(readFileSync(".levels/" + file, {encoding: "utf8"}))
    */
})

//but if your goal is just to print the file name you can do this
fs.readFileSync(".levels/").forEach(console.log)
```

Comment: do you have an idea how long this takes for 1K files? Are there any benchmarks?

Comment: it takes 100 units

Answer (score 1):

The only way to loop through directories and/or files is to use `fs` or some third party program like [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)

```
fs.readdirSync("path/to/folder").forEach(name => console.log(name))
```

This will print out the names of each file in the directory.

Comment: do you know how much time these file reads take on average?